# webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: not getting called on webkit with youtube video link iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using webkit to display YouTube videos on iOS4. Upon click on the video it should automatically launch the player and display the video, but what's happening is video is rendered in the player but under the webview. What I want to do is make webview's alpha 0 so I'm using delegate

```
      webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

But this delegate is not getting called when tapped on the video to launch it. It's otherwise getting called while the first webview itself is launched from the url.

### Edit

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

activityIndicatorView = [[ActivityIndicator alloc] init];

web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
web.delegate = self;
NSString *videoUrl = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
NSString *fullVdoUrl = [videoUrl stringByAppendingFormat:_videoUrl];

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:fullVdoUrl];   
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];           //Create a URL object.
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];            //URL Requst Object
[web loadRequest:requestObj];              //Load the request

[self.view addSubview:web];
[web release];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[activityIndicatorView.view removeFromSuperview];
web.alpha = 1.0;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {     
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView.view];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
web.alpha = 0.0;
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any answer? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: While I was playing around to achieve this, I found some error, and it gave the following log. It is evident from the log that the webview is internally using AVFoundation and Movie Player, perhaps we can use that info in some way? - 

2011-10-19 15:19:22.567 PlayYoutube[2720:707] _serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info -- notification=Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x19cf20 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}, AVPlayer = <MPQueuePlayer: 0x19dcb0>, currentTime = 0.00

Comment: maybe this helps: https://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3dfbd35e8db5729f/6d30915b2dbc1277, https://devforums.apple.com/message/26261#26261 . I think the problem is that the delegate doesn't get called, when the video is loaded with JavaScript. You may need to extend the JavaScript code, but this is not always possible, especially when using external sites.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

activityIndicatorView = [[ActivityIndicator alloc] init];

web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
web.delegate = self;
NSString *videoUrl = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
NSString *fullVdoUrl = [videoUrl stringByAppendingFormat:_videoUrl];

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:fullVdoUrl];   
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];           //Create a URL object.
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];            //URL Requst Object
[web loadRequest:requestObj];              //Load the request

[self.view addSubview:web];
[web release];

}
```

here:

**[self.view addSubview:web];**

self.view is nil and adding view to nil will notretain your webview.

**[web release];**

You are releasing webview which is having retain count 0.

try

```
self.view = web;
[web release];
```

this will work for you.